# How to make apple pie stay intact

Tags: baking, pie

I made an apple pie just the other day, and everything came out fine. The only problem was that the filling didn't stick to the crust (home made butter crust if it makes a difference). Is there anything I can do in order to make the filling stick to the crust?

Comment: Can you please edit this question to include your recipe and method so we can troubleshoot it for you?

Comment: Yes, please clarify what you mean by "filling stick to the crust". Do you have a gap? Is it too runny?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by having the filling 'stick' to the crust, but if you mean that the filling slides out, then you probably haven't added enough thickener (usually flour or cornstarch) to your apples, so the juices that leak out during cooking are too thin.

Different brands and batches of flour/cornstarch, and different apples, will have different levels of liquidity - a bit of practice and experience is necessary to get consistent results.

Comment: Flour sounds like a strange ingredient for apple pie filling; usually it'll be corn starch or tapioca starch. I suppose flour *could* work but you really only want the starch, not the protein.

Comment: My apple pie recipe comes from Bubby's in NYC: they seem to do pretty well using flour...

Comment: And a quick survey of recipes turn up plenty that use flour... http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/2052/ultimate-apple-pie
http://www.delish.com/recipefinder/deep-dish-apple-pie-recipe-8927
http://simplyrecipes.com/recipes/old_fashioned_apple_pie/
http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/bobby-flay/apple-pie-recipe/index.html

Comment: Nevertheless, Elendil, cornstarch is a far more common thickener in apple pie than flour ever is. Unless you'd like to have a word with a few of the pastry chefs I know and was taught by...?

Comment: Unless we compare every recipe known to man there's no way of knowing that for sure. Anyway, the point is, whatever thickening agent you use, if your filling is sliding out of the crust after cutting it needs more!

Comment: Forgive me for trusting my instructor (executive pastry chef at a large hotel, previously exec pastry chef in Dubai, has been baking for 30-odd years), a couple of French pastry chefs, my city's bets pastry chef, and a few others.

Comment: I've no doubt that he (and you) knows his stuff. Nor do I have any doubt that cornstarch is used to thicken many a pie filling. However, I also have no doubt that flour is as well, and that it is impossible to say objectively that cornstarch is used in more recipes than flour.

Comment: The fact that Aaronut (who knows a hell of a lot more than Ido) as well as multiple professional chefs say it.. whatever, dude.

Comment: Edited to reflect the variety of thickening agents used in pies...

Comment: Haha, don't use me as a source @daniel, my "usually" comment was just anecdotal (although I'm pretty sure the part about protein is correct). Sorry Elendil, didn't mean for it to turn into drama, but the edit should put any concerns to rest regardless.

Comment: Firstly I would like to thank you all for your response, you were right to assume that i meant that the filling falles out when i cut the pie. I use cornstach as a thickener but i guess i could try flour as well, but any how i will try to add more of the thickener and will post the results.

Comment: You're welcome. Stick with the thickener in your recipe just increase it a little at a time. You don't want apple glue pie!

Answer (score 0):

So much of making good apple pies relies on the apple type. You will never get the problem if you use Bramley apples, if you can't get those try to find Granny Smith apples.

Eating apples are really only good for making the sort of tartes the French make. If you are making pies, look for cooking apples.

Comment: I disagree. Cooking apples usually result in an apple mush. A nice eating apple like a Braeburn softens nicely but still holds its shape and thus provides some texture.

Comment: Though I would say I have seen a few recipes that use a mix of cooking and eating apples.

Comment: Bramleys keep texture if you bake them uncooked in small pies. They go mushy if you try to think large. My favourite is Wingate Wonder but that is a local thing - only get them from a local farm shop. Cooking apples with texture.

Comment: I would describe Granny Smith as "eating apples" (they are the kind I eat) and those were also the kind that I was taught to make apple pie with. Bramley are OK too, but I wouldn't use a true soft-and-sweet "cooking apple" in an apple pie, because as Elenedil says, they have a tendency to turn into mush and also become almost sickly-sweet.

Comment: As far as apple types go I will try the Granny Smith apples and will see how well the fare in my pie.
Thank you all.